# (Solved) How to uninstall default apps in Hera?

Tags: applications, default

Can anyone help me uninstalling the default apps in Hera?

Music, Videos, Calculator, Mail... all simply have no use for me and I'd like to keep my os clean.

However, I simply cannot find out what is the correct name of the default apps so I can remove them.

Thanks in advance.

---

**edit**: correct name of the apps are:

· Calculator: pantheon-calculator

· Mail: pantheon-mail

. Music: noise

· Photos: pantheon-photos

· Videos: audience

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Appcenter, open the Installed tab, and scroll down to the app you want to uninstall, click on it, then hit uninstall.

[image: Install a default app]

Answer (score 0):

On terminal, use: sudo apt remove name-of-the-app.

For example: `sudo apt remove pantheon-mail`